# Getting only one row per combination of two IDs

Tags: mysql

Below is an excerpt from a table containing messages that users have sent to eachother.

```
id | from_user | to_user | time 
---+-----------+---------+--------------------
 1 | 2         | 1       | 2016-01-03 01:22:14
 2 | 1         | 2       | 2016-01-03 01:26:20
 3 | 2         | 3       | 2016-01-03 01:27:39
 4 | 1         | 3       | 2016-01-03 08:15:11
 5 | 1         | 2       | 2016-01-03 09:44:51
 6 | 2         | 3       | 2016-01-03 10:13:13
 7 | 3         | 1       | 2016-01-03 11:29:19
 8 | 3         | 2       | 2016-01-03 14:54:41
```

Given this table I want to select the latest row per from_user/to_user combination, no matter if user 1 sent a message to user 2 or vice versa. The result for the above situation should thus look like this:

```
id | from_user | to_user | time 
---+-----------+---------+--------------------
 5 | 1         | 2       | 2016-01-03 09:44:51
 7 | 3         | 1       | 2016-01-03 11:29:19
 8 | 3         | 2       | 2016-01-03 14:54:41
```

So far I have tried to create a cartesian product from the user table with the following query:

```
SELECT a.id, b.id
FROM user a, user b
WHERE a.id < b.id
```

This works fine but now I have absolutely no idea how I can utilize this to loop through the "messages" table and retrieve the latest row per user combination.

I'd greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Take a look at GROUP BY and HAVING.

Comment: show your `messages` table

Comment: The "messages" table is the first table in my initial post.

@mzedeler: I know about GROUP BY and HAVING but can't figure out a way to make them do what I want unfortunately.